# How do you use Nant to build an ASP.Net MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, nant

Does anyone have an example nant build file to build an MVC2 project? I'm not sure whether you can use msbuild or whether you have to use aspnet_compiler or if nant will just handle it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [the msbuild task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc4/help/tasks/msbuild.html) on your solution file should build all projects in that solution, including MVC projects. Here's a sample from my own build script:

```
<target name="msbuild_solution">
    <msbuild project="build.sln"  verbosity="minimal">
        <property name="Configuration" value="Release" />
        <arg value="/t:Build" />
        <arg value="/nologo" />
        <arg value="/noconsolelogger" />
        <arg value="/m:2" />
        <arg value="/tv:3.5" />
    </msbuild>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this blog post?:

http://unethicalblogger.com/node/224

It was written for MVC1 so you might need to do some tweaking for MVC2.